# Heat loss in wheels

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, friction, angular-velocity

Is there a simple model for heat loss in car wheels that simply takes into account the width of the wheel and its angular speed? My guess is that if there is such a simple model, it would be a non-linear function of angular speed and vary linearly with the wheel width.

I'm assuming that the heat loss is mainly due to friction.

Comment: Have a look at rolling resistance. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small correction.

Heat loss on wheels is not due to friction because when the fictional force acts on the wheels the point of contact do not move and when that point has moved there is no force acting in direction of is motion and hence no work is done. The heat loss is due to cyclic contraction and expansion of the rubber of the wheels.